# Object slips out of gripper | Gazebo 7 | UR5 | Robotiq 3 finger

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

We want to manipulate some simple objects in Gazebo 7 using UR5 and Robotiq 3 finger gripper. We are using ROS indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

The **object slips out of the gripper every time**. Sample video: https://youtu.be/-YixCumWrt0

We have tried changing the mu1, mu2, kp, kd values of the gripper and the object. But no luck. We are using the Robotiq package from DRCSIM.

Have anyone faced similar issues? We will greatly appreciate a quick solution!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14887/object-slips-out-of-gripper-%7C-gazebo-7-%7C-ur5-%7C-robotiq-3-finger/) by [ariyan.kabir](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2918/ariyan.kabir/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here is an example tube that has been used in grasping tasks:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/92888709c301429ba1b5236063702857026c38cc/tube_9_5mm/model.sdf?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

In your world file, you can try this physics parameters:

```
<physics type="ode">
      <gravity>0.000000 0.000000 -9.810000</gravity>
      <ode>
        <solver>
          <type>quick</type>
          <iters>100</iters>
          <precon_iters>0</precon_iters>
          <sor>1.000000</sor>
        </solver>
        <constraints>
          <cfm>0.000000</cfm>
          <erp>0.500000</erp>
          <contact_max_correcting_vel>1000.000000</contact_max_correcting_vel>
          <contact_surface_layer>0.00000</contact_surface_layer>
        </constraints>
      </ode>
</physics>
```

Additionally:

1. Check the interia value of your tube. You can visualize the inertia in the GUI.
2. Try turning on collision visualizations, and see if the contacts are being created as you might expect.
3. What type of control for the hand are you using, position or torque?

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2